# My new electric kitchen stove stopped working

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, stove

I have a house that was built in the fifties,it has heavy wiring that comes from behind a cabinet for the stove. The plug in is on heavy wiring, is a three plug and matches the one that comes out from the stove.The bottom on plug that attaches to the big wiring feels loose. I had taped the plug with electrical tape and it worked when the new stove was put in but now stove has quit working,can you attach a new plug to this type of wiring?

Comment: Yes both the plug can be replaced.  One problem is it sounds like the old NEMA 10 type that was banned in the 90s for being unsafe.  Replacing with the safer NEMA 14 type might not be that hard.

Comment: Pictures would help. Also model # of the new stove.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you're describing the old-style 10-50 receptacle. One looks like this:

[image: 10-50 plug and receptacle]

Though these have been banned for new installations for decades, and they're somewhat dangerous, they are still manufactured and allowed as replacements. If the one you have is so loose that you needed to tape the plug in, a new receptacle will be significantly safer. The ideal case, of course, is to retrofit the outlet with ground and replace the receptacle with a 14-50, but even a proper 10-50 replacement has a benefit over a worn out one.

If you're comfortable replacing receptacles and have done it before yourself, you can replace this in most jurisdictions without an electrician. It's bigger than a standard receptacle, and less forgiving of failure, but it's not typically that complicated of an installation. If you're not comfortable, this is a straightforward replacement for any electrician.

One caveat: if the wiring going to the outlet right now is cloth-covered, you should probably get a pro in to do the replacement or quote an upgrade.